# Dictionary Comprehension within a List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries, that I'm modifying values in. I have a `for loop` that works as expected.

```py
show_mac = [{'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'GigabitEthernet1/1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'},
            {'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'TenGigabitEthernet2/1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'},
            {'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'Port-channel1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'}]

for d in show_mac:
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = (
            v.replace('TenGigabitEthernet', 'Te')
            .replace('GigabitEthernet', 'Gi')
            .replace('Port-channel', 'Po')
        )

pprint(show_mac)
```

Which produces this:

```py
[{'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'Gi1/1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'},
 {'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'Te2/1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'},
 {'mac': '0000.0000.0000', 'port': 'Po1', 'type': 'dynamic', 'vlan': '1'}]
```

I'm learning how to write comprehensions, and I'm trying to figure out how can I use list and dictionary comprehension on the above `for loop` to achieve the same results?

Comment: You possibly can do that, but why would you?  The `readability` will be sacrificed...

Comment: You don't use a comprehension to modify an object, it creates a new object.

Comment: If you're learning, then you should try to write this yourself rather than ask us to show you. If it doesn't work, post what you tried and we'll show you where you went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the key/value pairs. You know you want to modify the `port` value, so just do so directly. `for d in show_mac: d['port'] = d['port].replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`.

Comment: Part of learning how to write comprehensions is learning *when* to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to read/understand, but this works:

```
show_mac = [{key:value.replace('TenGigabitEthernet', 'Te').replace('GigabitEthernet', 'Gi').replace('Port-channel', 'Po') for (key, value) in line.items()}) for line in show_mac]
print(show_mac)
```

Comment: You don't need the name `new`; you can just write `show_mac = [...]`; the RHS side is fully evaluated before the result is assigned back to the name `show_mac`.

Comment: This unnecessarily recreates every `dict` as well.

Comment: @chepner you are right but this could just be an exercise in writing comprehensions; probably doesn't need to be too complex

Comment: This doesn't actually use a dictionary comprehension...